# How to create SESSION in Windows Phone

Tags: session, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

```
string uname = txt1.Text;
string pwd = txt2.Text;
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/newPage.xaml?name="+uname+"&pwd="+pwd,UriKind.Relative));
```

I have two text boxes: `username` and `password`
now I am entering values on those `textboxes` and those values are for example:

```
username: abcd
password:1234
```

now I want those values in multiple pages, so how it will possible?
I am using query string but every time I have to define values with `navigation URI`,
So please suggest me any other way like SESSION in ASP.NET.

Comment: you can use static variable for holding the values right?

Comment: how can I use it?I am new in windows phone applicaiton and its just about 1 month.So can you show me how to do it?

Comment: @VirajShah PhoneApplicationService.Current.State is another way to do your work.

Comment: @Jaihind can you show me by code? see my edited code.
I am using query string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the login is success, you can copy the Username and Password to static variables which have same namespace as of the app so that it will be accessible in every pages.

```
public static string Username;
public static string Password;
```

Hope this will solve your issue

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Users
 {
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
 }

  Users objUser = new Users();
  objUser.Username = "Viraj";
  objUser.Password = "12345";

//save data in phone state use in multiple pages.
      PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["UserInfo"] = objUser;

//To retrieve data on another screen from phone state

 if(PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["UserInfo"]!=null)
     {
       Users objUser = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["UserInfo"] as Users;
     } 

//To update data in phone state

  if(PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["UserInfo"]!=null)
    {
       Users objUser = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["UserInfo"] as Users;
       objUser.Username = "aman";
       PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["UserInfo"] = objUser;
     }

//at last remember that always remove data from phone state on app exist

private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
        {
          if(PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["UserInfo"]!=null)
                 {
                   PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Remove("UserInfo");
                 }
        }
```

Comment: +1 - When using PhoneApplicationService.Current.State, the data will be preserved while app is Tombstoned.

Answer (score 2):

Create a static public variable you set. Example:

```
public static class AppState
{
    public static string Username { get; set; }
    public static string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can simple set the values any where:

```
AppState.Username = "Viraj";
```

Comment: Thanks for reply brother but my username and password will be every time different.See my edited code.

Answer (score 0):

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["uname"] = uname;
```

then call it in other page like:

```
string name = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["uname"] as string;
```

this also works greater.