# Save values between page navigation in Windows Phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

How do I save values between page navigation in windows phone,
suppose I have two text blocks in my one phone application page, and they contains dynamically changing values every time, now suppose my text block have value "abc" and for some reason I go back to previous page, now when I get back on my page, I want that text block having value "abc". How to do it??

Comment: assign textblock value in a globally defined static variable.

Comment: @Jaihind how to do it..show me by code brother..thanks

Comment: I give a ans. Give a look and let me know if works or not.

Comment: There are various methods to save state of your variables. You can adapt most of the answers from [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22705291/2681948) for this purpose.

Comment: @Jaihind I am checking it..working on it..thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define two static variable in your App.xaml.cs

```
public static valueOne = string.Empty;
public static valueTwo = string.empty;

//Assign textbox value to variable on page leaving event
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
 {
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxOne.Text))
     App.valueOne = txtBoxOne.Text;
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxTwo.Text))
     App.valueTwo = txtBoxTwo.text;
 }
//Get value from page load
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
          if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(App.valueOne))
            string valueFirst =  App.valueOne;
         if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(App.valueTwo ))
            string valueTwo =  App.valueTwo ;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several methods available

- `IsolatedStorageSettings`

Save

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    // txtInput is a TextBox defined in XAML.
    if (!settings.Contains("userData"))
    {
        settings.Add("userData", txtInput.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        settings["userData"] = txtInput.Text;
    }
    settings.Save();
```

Read

```
if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("userData"))
    {
        txtDisplay.Text +=
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["userData"] as string;
    }
```

- `PhoneApplicationService.Current.State`

`PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["param"] = param`

and on other page we can get it like this.

```
var k = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["param"];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various approaches to solve this. 
Common thing is using a Static Class, which holds static properties and binding it to your View.